# Add a textbox to a wpf canvas in a position chosen by the user (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I would like to add a functionality to a WPF C# app that allows the user to do the following:

When you press a button, a textbox is created in the corner of a canvas, when you're done typing and you press the button again, the next click will set the new position of this textbox on the canvas.

I tried writing the code but it doesn't look very solid, plus I get an error explained below:

```
int i = 0;

System.Windows.Point currentPoint = new System.Windows.Point();

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e2)
{
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        TextBlock TB = new TextBlock();
        TB.Text = "Successfull";
        TB.Background = Brushes.White;
        TB.Name = "TextB";
        myCanvas.Children.Add(TB);

        Canvas.SetLeft(TB, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(TB, 10);
    }

    if (i == 2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        while (e2.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
             Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        if (e2.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            currentPoint = e2.GetPosition(this);
            Canvas.SetLeft(TB, currentPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(TB, currentPoint.Y);
        }
        i=0;
    }

}
```

However I declared my textbox (TB) inside of an "if" statement, so when I try to modify its position, it is considered unknown `Canvas.SetLeft(TB, currentPoint.X);`
. If I declare it outside, the textbox will be created even if the button isn't pressed. Any ideas?

Also if you have another solution that looks less ugly, feel free to share!

Answer (score 0):

A potential (but to be honest with you a quick & dirty one), solution could be the following MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasTextBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="OnButtonClick" >Click Me</Button>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="LightSkyBlue" 
            x:Name="PositioningCanvas"
            PreviewMouseUp="OnPreviewMouseUp">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Visibility="Collapsed" MinWidth="80" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

With the MainWindow.cs like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool isTextEditing;

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isTextEditing)
        {
            TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            isTextEditing = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isTextEditing = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // As long as your TextBox.Visibility is Collapsed and the user is in 'textEditing' after the
        // first click, don't handle clicks in the Canvas
        if (!isTextEditing && TextBox.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(PositioningCanvas);
            Canvas.SetTop(TextBox, clickPoint.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(TextBox, clickPoint.X);
        }
    }
```