# how to display or draw text inside inkcanvas wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

We are using ink canvas control on the page and I want to display text inside the control without adding child control in the control because we need stroke collection of this text through which we can show revert back this ink canvas  data(stroke collection) in the control when we need. Is this possible?
or we can type text in the ink canvas control from the keyboard?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can i type text inside the Ink canvas control? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a TextBox to a (ink)canvas, so you cannot literally type text into a canvas. You could however fake this by letting a TextBox appear over the canvas  on the position of a mouseclick. Then the user can type in what he wants it to say and add that piece of text to the canvas as you normally would.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565279/add-a-textbox-to-a-wpf-canvas-in-a-position-chosen-by-the-user-c) post to see a simple way of doing so.